# Awesome WM tiles KDE networking and battery widget

Tags: awesome, plasma

I currently use KDE with Awesome WM. I got the KDE bar at the bottom hidden, but I can un-hide with with the cursor when I need to use the Plasma Network Manager.

With KWin, they would appear like little drawers from the bottom and where quite usable. With Awesome WM, these get tiled as well, making them pretty hard to use:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2013-12-09/screenshot4.png

Is there some way to fix this? I tried setting `floating = true` for the class `plasma-desktop`, but that did not change anything.

This is what I got with `sleep 10 && xprop` and clicking on the networking widget when it was extended:

```
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 31457739
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 14075167
_NET_STARTUP_ID(UTF8_STRING) = "0"
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 4294967295
_KDE_SHADOW_OVERRIDE(_KDE_SHADOW_OVERRIDE) = 0x1
_KDE_NET_WM_SHADOW(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1e00004
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 2404
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _KDE_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_OVERRIDE, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_NAME(STRING) = "plasma-desktop"
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "de_DE.UTF-8"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "plasma-desktop", "Plasma-desktop"
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
                Client accepts input or input focus: True
                Initial state is Normal State.
                window id # of group leader: 0x1e00004
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                user specified location: 1367, 20
                program specified location: 1367, 20
                user specified size: 838 by 1029
                program specified size: 838 by 1029
                program specified minimum size: 316 by 308
                program specified maximum size: 1680 by 1050
                window gravity: Static
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "Martin-X220"
WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "/usr/bin/plasma-desktop" }
```

Comment: Are you sure those windows have the class value `plasma-desktop`?  What does the program `xprop` print out for `WM_CLASS` for those windows?

Comment: I tried a `sleep 10 && xprop` and clicked on the network manager drawer. So I have no idea how I could check that otherwise.

Comment: And what did it actually print out?  Window class names are usually capitalized.  (You realize that the "class" of the window is the *second* string that `xprop` prints out (the first string being the "instance")...)

Comment: Could you make the capitalization as an answer? I changed it to `Plasma-desktop` and it works now. I'd like to give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've correctly identified the class name of the window you're trying to construct a rule for.  By convention, window class names are capitalized.  You can use the program `xprop` to discover the correct class name.  As an example, for this terminal program I have open, `xprop` prints out:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "x-terminal-emulator", "URxvt"
```

The first string is the "instance" name (usually the name used to launch the program); the second string is the "class".

This is all discussed at length in [Understanding Rules](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Understanding_Rules), a page I wrote on Awesome's Wiki a little while back.